# INNER JOIN works with * but not with a single field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

If i use the following line in PHP the MySQL query works perfectly fine:

```
$query = "
SELECT * 
  FROM customers_1 
  JOIN customers_2 
    ON customers_1.id = customers_2.cus_id;
";
```

but when i try to just get two single fields like this:

```
$query = "
SELECT customers_1.product,customers_1.id
  FROM customers_1 
  JOIN customers_2 
    ON customers_1.id = customers_2.cus_id;
";
```

it doesnt work at all, means i do not get any output. When i copy and paste the second query and put it into PHPMyAdmin it works perfectly fine.

What i do afterwards is this:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($row['id']=="3")
    {
        foreach($row as $field)
        {
            echo $field;
        }
    }
}

mysql_close($dbhandle);
```

Comment: Check if the column `product` is present in both tables.

Comment: where is id field ($row['id']) in query  ?

Comment: mysql_* extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0. The [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used

Comment: I'm not a php guy, but this looks problematic, `if($row['id']=="3")`  Maybe there is no matching row.  Or, if `id` is supposed to come from the query, you aren't selecting it.  Mind you, that should throw an error for an undefined variable.

Comment: Is there any sense to use _id_ without fetch by select statement? Second select query require to fetch _id_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing `id` in your code while your query is retrieving `customers_1.product`.

Comment: im sorryy i edited the original for this post and made a mistake in changing, i get the field id of course

Answer (score 1):

Because `$row['id']` is nothing in your code because you just `fetch one column` from your query `SELECT customers_1.product..` and that column is `product`

And no need  `foreach` loop . You just get your value in single while loop

**Updated Answer after question updated**

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            if (!empty($row['id'])) {
                echo $row['id'];
            }
        }
```

> Note:- Mysql is deprecated instead use mysqli or PDO

Comment: im sorryy i edited the original for this post and made a mistake in changing, i get the field id of course